# "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted." Need to return a set of values

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
var range = this.dataStore.Query<NotificationConfiguration>()
                .Range(p => new NotificationConfigurationViewModel(p, from x in p.Events where !(x.Code == null || x.Code.Equals("")) select x.Code), pageNumber);

return this.View(range);
```

I have the above code in which I want to return an IEnumerable but get a 
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression" every time the code is run. I understand that the query wants to return just one value, but how do I get it to return a set of values as intended? Help please!

Let me clarify a little... I want the range to include a new object. I have a query which is going through the database. It returns the data which I then convert using the following view model constructor:

```
public NotificationConfigurationViewModel(NotificationConfiguration notification , IEnumerable<string> codes)
{
    Contract.Requires(notification != null);

    this.notification = notification;
    this.codes = codes;
}
```

Each Notification Configuration has properties and then a list of events tied to it. I need just the codes from said list.

---

Just to clarify again. I want the query to give me back a NotificationConfiguration and also an IEnumerable (which I will later transform to a single string using SB). Once the query gives me back those two items I will transform it using a constructor in my view model so I can properly display all the data using a DataTable. The answer I am looking for maybe very specific but I need to understand why I'm getting the subquery error when I want it to return an IEnumerable and how to fix it. Also please note... according to the .net docs the code should be handing my back an IEnumerable but for some reason its still crashing. Here is the relevant code samples again:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DataTableRequest requestedData)
    {
        using (this.dataStore.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            return this.dataStore.Query<NotificationConfiguration>()
                          .TableRange(requestedData, p => new NotificationConfigurationViewModel(p, from x in p.Events select x.Code));
        }
    }
```

.

```
        public NotificationConfigurationViewModel(NotificationConfiguration notification , IEnumerable<string> events)
    {
        Contract.Requires(notification != null);

        this.notification = notification;
        this.events = events;
    }
```

.

```
    [Display(Name = "Events")]
    public virtual string EventTypeCodes
    {
        get
        {
            var codes = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in this.events)
            {
               codes.Append(item + ",");
            }

            return codes.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
        }
    }
```

Comment: use the FirstOrDefault() , or First() method on the inner query

Comment: I can't us First() or FirstOrDefault(). I need to return a set of code values. Preferably an IEnumerable<string> as code is a string.

Comment: Could you trace the real query executed on the database ? This error is thrown when you make something like this: ""select *** where id= (select id from ...) "" and your subselect returns more than 1 record

Comment: You should use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) rather than `(x.Code == null || x.Code.Equals("")`

Comment: What do you expect the range to return? Or specifically where should it start?

Comment: In my code I am taking a range of NotificationConfigurations and transforming it to a range of NotificationConfigurationViewModel so I can return it to a view where I use a DataTable to spit out the data. I have a constructor for the transformation which takes in the notification configuration along with an IEnumerable<string> that contains all the codes that I need to display as a single string later within the code using a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is with [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) method (copied below).

```
.Range(p => new NotificationConfigurationViewModel(p, from x in p.Events where !(x.Code == null || x.Code.Equals("")) select x.Code), pageNumber);
```

The [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) expects the caller to pass in the following arguments:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(
    int start,
    int count
)
```

The code is passing in `(NotificationConfigurationViewModel, int)`. This certainly seems to be part of the issue. I believe that the appropriate solution would be the following:

```
var range = from p in this.dataStore.Query<NotificationConfiguration>()
select new NotificationConfigurationViewModel(p, p.Events.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Code)));
```

This will convert from your `NotificationConfiguration` to `NotificationConfigurationViewModel` while not including any codes that are empty strings.

Comment: I agree, my comment should have been more elaborated: either return the first element from the inner query, or change the outer query so that it can handle more than one result

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is in the query, not the data set, so to give an exact answer we need to see the query. However in general there are a few constructs you can use. You probably have something like WHERE Id = (SELECT ID FROM Values WHERE DateOFValues BETWEEN FirstDate AND LastDate). WHAT YOU Want is WHERE ID IN (SELEct... OR WHERE IS = ANY (SELECT... or a sub query  in which case look here... http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html (yes I know it says access, but MS SQL supports all the sytax used here.

Answer (score 0):

Going on assumptions... is this what you are after?

If you are trying to create a bunch of new objects, the object creation is best done inside the select part of the query.

```
int pageNumber = 0;
int pageSize = 10;

IQueryable<NotificationConfiguration> configurations = this.dataStore.Query<NotificationConfiguration>();

IList<NotificationConfigurationViewModel> viewModels =
    (from configuration in configurations
     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration.Code)
     select new NotificationConfigurationViewModel(configuration))
    .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

return viewModels;
```